# Generic Ionic app doesn't load in AVD

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-virtual-device

My android virtual device starts up fine. But when it goes to load my ionic app it says: "app-name has stopped", "Open app again" after opening the app several times it says: "app-name keeps stopping close app". My app is the base tabs ionic app.

Ionic even says launch success...

I've tried different AVDs but none have worked. Here are the stats on my current one.

[image: avd stats]

I've tried running it in with `ionic run android -c -1` but all it says is

`emulator: Requested console port 5584: Inferring adb port 5585.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5584
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5584`

EDIT: it works on Ionic serve just doesn't load on the android virtual device.

Comment: You've executed on a device? or ionic serve --lab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking use host GPU in the android SDK manager solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

check if you have a service using that port or a program like skype that uses that port, then close or change the port it uses.

i had to close xampp in order to emulate android.